# Instance method reference of a null object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, method-reference, ecj

What is the right behavior according to JLS when `methodReferenceOfNullObject()` is invoked?

- throw a `NullPointerException` (Oracle Java Compiler) or
- assign supplier to `result` though `o` is `null` (Eclipse Java Compiler)

  ```
  public void methodReferenceOfNullObject() {
      Object o = nullReference();

      Supplier<String> result = o::toString; // <-- point of interest

      ...
  }

  private Object nullReference() {
      return null;
  }
  ```

Comment: try running the code and see what happends.

Comment: @Aomine: The question shows two different behaviors on two different compilers. The OP *did* try it, saw what happened, and is asking which behavior is correct.

Comment: @DanielPryden Right, my bad for misreading the description.